# Why does the HSV-to-RGB algorithm work the way it does?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics, colors

I have read the Wikipedia article about [converting from HSV to RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV), but I don't understand. Why is each case option the way it is, and why they are ordered like that, if the order matters?

Comment: Please copy the relevant code into your question. Be specific. I don't want to have to go somewhere else to figure out what you're referring to.

Comment: You have already asked the same question, and gotten both links and an answer.

Comment: I previously asked the question but it seems it was closed for "being a duplicate", I asked it differently since I suppose people are confused about what I am asking.

Comment: Why downvote? It is marked as a "possible duplicated" (which I still contend it is not). The downvote is unwarranted.

Comment: Voted to reopen. This question asks for an explanation of the algorithm; the others don't ask that.

Comment: People vote questions down when they're unclear or not useful. Your question obviously wasn't clear, Jude, since at least five people thought it was a duplicate of two other questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wikipedia outlines a pretty bulletproof approach to coding it, so I'll assume you're confused about the implementation's logic. You're confused about this, correct?

[image]

If you look at the image adjacent to it, you will see why:

[image]

Each channel's function is a piecewise function consisting of five linear segments. The cases account for each range of each distribution, namely the shaded regions of the above picture.