# RGB to HSB Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm to convert RGB to HSV and HSV to RGB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018313/algorithm-to-convert-rgb-to-hsv-and-hsv-to-rgb)

I'm trying to find an algorithm (prefferabley represented in C++) that converts from RGBto HSB values so that I can process it accordingly. Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: LMGTFY: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018313/algorithm-to-convert-rgb-to-hsv-and-hsv-to-rgb and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215901/why-does-the-hsv-to-rgb-algorithm-work-the-way-it-does

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's java and not C++ but it should be close enough to be easily reusable. Look for the `RGBtoHSB` method in this page:

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/awt/Color.java.html

Answer (score 3):

There's a number of colour algorithms demonstrated [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html), including the one you require which would be worth reading.